# JavaScript "Floats", or ThreeJS wrong positioning?

Tags: vector, linear-algebra, floating-point

I want to learn how to use Vectors with 3D.

Here is a strange Error I have encountered today.

Instead of stopping exactly on the other Cube, I get this:
[image]

When I change the IF to (cube.position.y < 0.1) OR change the speed to 0.01, it lands on the other cube.  Seems 0.1 is the Magic Number.. But why?
Why does 0.9 and 0.8 seem fine, but then it Jumps into lengthy numbers?
This looks more like ThreeJS is moving the Cube inaccurately, rather then JavaScript being unable to move an Object 0.1 sizes.

Such a beginner problem, but this is baffling to me..

Why does this happen? And how can I change it?

Is this where I "normalise" the Vector?

Comment: This isn't really gamedev related. Also this might be worthwhile to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ivan Kucklr says, floating point values are binary and decimal values such as 0.1 may not be represented exactly. This is true across languages, and is not Javascript specific or Three.js specific. It's fine some of the time, but often bites you worse when [repeatedly adding or subtracting](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/propagation/) like your program does.

In your program, you're waiting for `cube2.position.y` to reach 0. When it's > 0 you subtract 0.1. But what's happening is that it's reaching some number very close to 0, but not exactly 0. Sometimes it'll overshoot a little; sometimes it'll undershoot. In this case it's undershooting slightly which means you end up running your loop one extra time.

Instead of checking whether it's reached 0, you can check whether it's reached *close* to 0. The easiest thing in this particular case is to test `if (cube2.position.y > 0.00001)`. More generally, if you want to know whether `a == b`, you can instead use `abs(a - b) < epsilon` where epsilon is some small number relative to the expected size of a and b; instead of `a > b` you can use `(a - b) > epsilon`.

Read more on [this page](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm), which goes through an example of 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 != 0.1 * 10, just like your program, but then shows some more advanced ways to compare.

Answer (score 0):

You can not "trust" floating point values. First, 0.1 can not be represented in binary system. It is periodical and it should be approximated by finite mantissa.

So, imagine this program on decimal computer:

```
var i = 1;
while( i>0 ) i -= 1/3;
console.log(i);           // prints -0.3333333332
```

1/3 will be approximated as 0.33333333, so values of "i" will be

```
 1.0000000000
 0.6666666667
 0.3333333334
 0.0000000001
-0.3333333332
```